# Get all namespaces of projects referenced in a console app

Tags: .net, assemblies

I have a console app and I added a reference to 2 projects to this console app, CustomerService.DataAccess and CustomerService.Business, Now, when the console app runs i would like to get all namespaces that are in the 2 projects that i added to the console app. Thankx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you need to first get the referenced assemblies, and then get the set of namespaces from all of the types in that assembly.

```
AssemblyName[] referencedAssemblies = GetType().Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();
HashSet<string > namespaces = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (AssemblyName referencedAssembly in referencedAssemblies)
{
    Assembly reference = Assembly.Load(referencedAssembly);

    if (!reference.GlobalAssemblyCache)
    {
        HashSet<string> refernceNamespaces = new HashSet<string>(
            reference.GetTypes().Select(t => t.Namespace).Where(ns => ns != null));
        namespaces.UnionWith(refernceNamespaces);
    }
}
```

The code above will get all of the namespaces in referenced assemblies that are not in the GAC. If you only want to get the namespaces in your specific assemblies, you can just check the [`AssemblyName.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.name.aspx) property to make sure you are inspecting the correct assemblies.

Comment: You don't need to reload the assemblies - you can get at the actual Assembly instance through AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

Comment: Did you mean Excecutingassembly by GetType() in that first line of code?

Comment: @zebrabox you could indeed, but calling `Assembly.Load` on an already loaded assembly does not load another copy of it, it just returns the already loaded assembly. As the assembly is referenced anyway, there will be no additional overhead.

Comment: @user282807 `GetType()` will get the type of the current object, which in your console application will be the type where the above code lives. You could use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` instead of `GetType().Assembly` if you prefer.

Comment: @adrianbanks - Ah, didn't know LoadAssembly did that - learn something new everyday etc :)

Comment: @zebrabox I had to check it myself. Using both object IDs in the debugger and fusion log loading, it does confirm this behaviour.

Comment: @adrianbanks I did var y = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies(); and all this returned was 1)mscorlib, 2)System.XML.LINQ, and 3)System.core. I didnt see the other 2 I am looking for that i referenced.

Comment: @user282807 are you actually using any objects from those two assemblies - if not, they will not be added as references when you compile.

Comment: @adrianbanks Oh ok, i wasnt using anything from them. I wanted to see if we could still get a list of everything someone would add as a reference to a project. But I will run your code and actually use some class from the referenced assemblies i added.

Comment: @adrianbanks hi thanks, your code works great, actually got all the namespaces from the project i referenced once i instanciated an object from it.